# Define wsdl2java arguments in pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, cxf

I'm new with Maven and CXF and I'm trying to setup the pom.xml to generate code with wsdl2java. I have some arguments that I need to add to the `wsdl2java` command but I'm not sure how.

This is how the command would look at the terminal:

```
wsdl2java -fe jaxws21 -d gen -validate -p com.example -faultSerialVersionUID FQCN -asyncMethods -bareMethods -exceptionSuper com.example.ExampleException wsdl/objects.wsdl
```

In my pom.xml I have the following:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-sources</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/cxf</sourceRoot>
                <wsdlOptions>
                    <wsdlOption>
                        <wsdl>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/objects.wsdl</wsdl>
                        <wsdlLocation>classpath:wsdl/objects.wsdl</wsdlLocation>
                    </wsdlOption>
                </wsdlOptions>
                <defaultOptions>
                    <markGenerated>true</markGenerated>
                    <asyncMethods />
                    <bareMethods />
                </defaultOptions>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I'm pretty sure I got the asyncMethods and bareMethods arguments correctly since the code generates ok. I'm curious on a couple of things though.

I'm wondering on how to:

- add the `-fe` argument together with the `jaxws21` value
- add the `-p` argument with the `com.example` value
- add the `-faultSerialVersionUID` with the `FQCN` value
- add the `-exceptionSuper` with the `com.example.ExampleException` value

I've tried to read the CXF docs, SO, Google and many other places. I've read through many different xml files by googling "cxf pom filetype:xml". Unfortunately, I haven't been able to figure this last bit out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how the configuration looks based on your question:

```
... ...    

<defaultOptions>
    <markGenerated>true</markGenerated>
    <asyncMethods />
    <bareMethods />
    <!-- add the -fe argument together with the jaxws21 value -->
    <frontEnd>jaxws21</frontEnd>
    <!-- add the -p argument with the com.example value -->
    <packagenames>
        <packagename>com.example</packagename>
    </packagenames>
    <!-- add the -faultSerialVersionUID with the FQCN value -->
    <faultSerialVersionUID>FQCN</faultSerialVersionUID>
    <!-- add the -exceptionSuper with the com.example.ExampleException value -->
    <exceptionSuper>com.example.ExampleException</exceptionSuper>
</defaultOptions>

... ...
```

You can decomplie cxf-codegen-plugin.jar and directly look into the source to see how it parse these command line arguments, more specifically, this class:

[org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.wsdl2java.WsdlOption](http://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/maven_plugin/wsdl2java/WsdlOption.html)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh the awsomess! Will look into this as soon as possible. Looks good!